# SQL Server: convert common date column data to date with timezone

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

I'm struggling with this: I have a table called `Foo` with a `datetime` column (without timezone info). However, we're doing such an "internationalization" effort, and now we need to store datetime with timezone info (`datetimeoffset` column type).

Assuming that all pre-existing datetime data uses `-03:00` (America/São Paulo - Brasília) timezone, and `CONVERT(varchar(50), foo.date, 127)` returns something like `2012-04-17T01:14:33`, how should I proceed to get ISO 8601 datetime string (something like `2012-04-17T04:14:33Z` or `2012-04-17T01:14:33 -03:00`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recognize that both Brasília and São Paulo observe [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) for part of the year, so it is not just a simple conversion to `-03:00`.  If it were fixed to that offset, you could just use the `TODATETIMEOFFSET` function - but you can't.  There are two different offsets to consider. `-03:00` for standard time, and `-02:00` when daylight saving time is in effect.

Determining when DST should be in effect in Brazil is not the easiest thing, as there has been a complex history of changes.  The current rule can be found [here in the tzdb](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/3a337b12e81595c328c414cc2ac68f214da3d841/southamerica#L934-L951), which currently says (since 2008) to start DST on the 3rd Sunday in October, and end it on the 3rd Sunday in February - *unless* that day happens to be the [Carnival Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Carnival), in which case DST ends on the 4th Sunday in February instead.

Sure, you could codify those rules into a stored procedure or user-defined function, but that would be quite complicated.

There are two better approaches worth considering:

1. You could write a SQL CLR function.  If you do, you have two sub-options:

   - If the server's local time zone where you're going to be doing the conversions is set for Brasilia, then you can simply use `new DateTimeOffset(yourDateTime)` - which will pick the appropriate offset based on the local time zone.
   - You could use the `TimeZoneInfo` class, but it will require [Unsafe Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx) be enabled.  If you do, the conversion would look like this:

     ```
     var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
     var dto = new DateTimeOffset(yourDateTime, tz.GetUtcOffset(yourDateTime));
     ```
2. You can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project, which incorporates all of the correct time zone conversions, and gives you some simple functions ready to go.

   ```
   DECLARE @tz varchar(25)
   SET @tz = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
   SELECT Tzdb.SwitchZone(Tzdb.LocalToUtc(YourDateTime, @tz, 1, 1), @tz);
   ```

   Notice that I first convert the local time to UTC, then switch it back to the original time zone.  I'll [probably update the project to include this as a single function](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport/issues/7), but for now the two will work.

Of course with either of these options, you'd need to write an `UPDATE` statement.  I suggest creating a new column, then updating that column, then removing the original column only after you're satisfied with the conversion.  Don't try to change the type of the existing column in place.   Alternatively, you could create a new table and do the conversions by selecting from one table and inserting into the other.

Lastly, consider that when a time zone has DST, any time you convert from local time to an instantaneous point in time (whether that be a UTC `datetime`, or a `datetimeoffset`) - there is potential for ambiguity.  This occurs because of the "fall-back" transition, which creates an overlap of local time values when DST ends.  For example, in your time zone DST will next start on `2015-10-18 00:00:00`, and will end on `2016-02-21 00:00:00`.  When DST ends, values from `2016-02-20 23:00:00` through `2016-02-20 23:59:59.9999999` are ambiguous.  They might have an offset of `-02:00` if they refer to the occurrence that happens *before* DST ends, or they might have an offset of `-03:00` if they refer to the occurrence that happens *after* DST ends.

In my above recommendations, both options in recommendation #1 will chose the *later* occurrence in case of ambiguity.  If you go with recommendation #2, you can control this behavior with the bit flags on the `LocalToUtc` function.  The options I showed above chose the *earlier* occurrence in the ambiguous case - which is usually preferred (IMHO).  [The project's readme file](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport/blob/master/README.md) has more details on these options and how they control both ambiguous-time and invalid-time behavior.

Also consider that if you have some other column in your database that is incremental, such as an integer ID column, and you happen to have rows in the ambiguous period that are both before and after the transition, you might be able to sort them by that secondary column in order to disambiguate.  This usually requires manual review of the data over the period of ambiguity - or some other fancy footwork in your update statements, but it is possible in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try your project. I figured out I didn't care about daylight saving time before reading your answer. I'll check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command. It Worked for me.

```
SELECT CAST(<ColumnName> AS datetimeoffset)
FROM <TableName>
```

IF you are wanting to update your tables information I would try this.

```
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <DateColumn> = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, <DateColumn>)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This works, but how should I proceed to set the timezone to -03:00 for all data in table?

Comment: Use this statement SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET (<datecolumn>, '-03:00');

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help you [SWITCHOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx)

Syntax

```
SWITCHOFFSET ( DATETIMEOFFSET, time_zone )
```

Code

```
--SELECT SWITCHOFFSET (ColDatetimeoffset, '-03:00') 
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() CurrentOffset
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-03:00')
```

see this also [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 126)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 127)
```

[image: CAST and CONVERT]

Comment: Actually `TODATETIMEOFFSET` would be more appropriate than `SWITCHOFFSET`, but unfortunately neither will consider DST so they will not help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a better formatter if you use a .NET CLR function.  To do this, you will need to have a version of Visual Studio installed.  Create a database project:
[image]

From the Database project right click and do Add -> New Item..
[image]
Select SQL CLR C# User Defined Function
[image]
Then cut and paste this into your class

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(Name = "FormatDate")]
    public static SqlString FormatDate(SqlDateTime date, SqlString formatString)
    {
        var thisDate = date.Value;
        return new SqlString (thisDate.ToString(formatString.Value));
    }
    [SqlFunction(Name = "FormatDateTimeOffset")]
    public static SqlString FormatDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset date, SqlString formatString)
    {
        return new SqlString(date.ToString(formatString.Value));
    }    
}
```

Right click on the Project and select publish put in your database connection info and publish and then you can run queries like:

```
select dbo.FormatDate(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ''GMT'' zzz') as "DateTime"
select dbo.FormatDateTimeOffset(convert(datetimeoffset, getdate()), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss K') as "DateTimeOffset"
```

...and get results like:

[image]

Comment: The question was about time zone conversion - not about string formatting.

Comment: So what is time zone conversion if not displaying the time with a Timezone and offset as to where the time was recorded.  It's totally about format.  Perhaps you should re-read before you down vote something you clearly don't understand.

Comment: Moreover, every example posted here does a CAST or CONVERT, which does exactly what?  Changes the representation of what is displayed...hence a different way to format data.  I guess you will be down-voting all the rest as they do not conform to your understanding of the question.

Comment: Uh... check my profile.  I understand this area quite well.  Thank you.   The point is - you have delivered a `varchar`, and the solution requires a `datetimeoffset`.  There is a way to do this with SQL CLR, but not the way you showed.

Comment: If you'd like me to remove the downvote, please update your answer to show one or both of the SQL CLR approaches I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Matt you are a funny guy.  You downvote me for giving a varchar answer, when your own solution provides a varchar answer.  Irony much. I will wear your disapproving downvote with honor now.

Comment: Sorry, no.  My answer provides a value of `datetimeoffset` type.  Also, I'm not sure why you've decided to resort to [ad hominem](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/ad-hominem).  You'll find that the  StackOverflow community prefers objectivity.

Comment: Ok the poster stated "how should I proceed to get ISO 8601 datetime string" I produced something that produced a string in the format that he/she required and not by simply copying-n-pasting docs but exerted an actual effort to help and now I am being accused of insulting your character somehow.  I like your "If you want me to remove the downvote...please agree with me".  And I am not being objective.  So there is only one solution?

Comment: Actually, you make a good point.  I did not see the word "string" in the OP.  Though it's not the ideal approach, it is part of what was asked - my sincere apologies.  Unfortunately, SO won't let me undo the downvote without an edit, so please make a trivial edit and I'll upvote.  Thanks.